# Java 8 sort on Class member's property

Tags: java, java-8

Class declaration:

```
class Entity {
    String name;
    SubEntity subEntity; // subEntity has a method getAmount() which returns int
}
```

I understand with Java 8 we can sort like:

```
entities.sort(Comparator.comparing(Entity::name));
```

But is there a way I can sort it on sub-entities' properties, for eg:

```
entities.sort(Comparator.comparing(Entity::SubEntity::getAmount()));
```

P.S: All in for any one-liners.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There's no reason multiple potential answerers should each come up with their own test bed for this when you presumably already have something close to being right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Guys gave you good answers. It isn't supposed to be an improvement over their answers. I just want to provide an alternative idea.*

```
entities.sort(Comparator.comparing(((Function<Entity, SubEntity>)Entity::getSubEntity).andThen(SubEntity::getAmount)));
```

I formed a key extractor by combining two functions `Entity::getSubEntity` and `SubEntity::getAmount` with [`Function#andThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-). Both have been written as method references. The cast is required to determine the type of an instance and call `andThen` on that instance.

Comment: All provided excellent answers but this is what I was looking for, extracting a function reference from child object. Thanks man!!

Comment: But seriously, `((Function<Entity, SubEntity>)Entity::getSubEntity).andThen(SubEntity::getAmount)` is not an improvement over `e -> e.getSubEntity().getAmount()`…

Comment: Not when you're a fan of BDD.

Comment: In my case I had to sort by many elements in the sub entity so this answer actually helped me more than the others. I broke Function<Entity, SubEntity> getSub = Entity::getSubEntity onto it's own line and reused this for each comparing function like. entities.sort(Comparator.comparing(getSub.andThen(SubEntity::getCol1)).thenComparing(getSub.andThen(SubEntity::getCol2)).thenComparing...

Answer (score 10):

Not by using a method reference, no - but it's easy to do with a lambda instead:

```
entities.sort(Comparator.comparing(entity -> entity.getSubEntity().getAmount()));
```

Fundamentally there's nothing magical about `Comparator.comparing` - it just accepts a `Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor` parameter, so you need to work out some way of creating such a function. A method reference is one convenient way of creating a function, but a lambda expression is more flexible one.

Comment: but this does not compile:


ees.sort(Comparator.comparing(ee -> ee.getStart()).thenComparing(EE::getStart));

Comment: @SachinVerma you need to add a bit more type information most probably for it to work: `Comparator.comparing((Entity x) -> x.getSubEntity().getFirst()).thenComparing(x -> x.getSubEntity().getSecond())`

Comment: You may using `comparingInt` to potentially save some CPU cycles…

Answer (score 5):

You can do that via a lambda as opposed to a method reference:

```
 entities.sort(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getSubEntity().getAmount())
```

If you you have indeed an `int` as you say in your comments, then use :

```
 Comparator.comparingInt(...)
```

Comment: I am assuming you're using `comparing` rather than the primitive variants due to not knowing the type of `getAmount`?

Comment: @Aominè *exactly*, but worth a suggestion indeed as Holger just made the same comment to the other answer