# How to Sort List based on Inner Object's property in java 8

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-stream, comparator

I have classes structure similar to:

```
    class FinalResponse {
        Source source;
        List<Target> targets;
    }
    
    class Response {
    Source source;
    Target target;
   }

    class Source {
        Long sourceId;
        String sourceName;
    }
    
    class Target {
        Long targetId;
        String targetName;
    }
```

I have two different tables `Source` and `Target`, and after joining them I am getting four columns in the query output. I am constructing `Response` object using values of these four columns. I have data in Response object with these 4 properties `sourceId, sourceName, targetId, targetName`.
I can have `sourceId, sourceName` same on the multiple rows but `targetId, targetName` will always be different.

I grouped all the `target` objects into the List for which `source` is the same.

```
List<FinalResponse> finalResponses = responses.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Response::getSource,
        LinkedHashmap::new,
        Collectors.mapping(Response::getTarget, Collectors.toList())
    )) // Map<Source, List<Target>> is built
    .entrySet()
    .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<Source, List<Target>>>
    .map(e -> new FinalResponse(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But sometimes reponse from database cannot be sorted and even though it is sorted and I have used `LinkedHashmap::new` then also my final output `List<FinalResponse> finalResponses` is not sorted.
I wanted my final output to be sorted as per sourceId, so I did:

```
finalResponses.sort(Comparator.comparing(finalResponse->finalResponse.getSource().getSourceId()));
```

It is working fine for non null values but if I have `source(sourceId=null,sourceName=null)` on multiple rows then I am getting `NullPointerException`.
What is the best approach to Sort Collection based on `Source` Object's `sourceId` property ?

Comment: Are the null source fields acceptable in your problem domain, or is that a problem/bug? And if you do allow null source data, how do you expect to use `Source` as a key in a map?

Comment: @basil-bourque It is not the problem, it is allowed sometimes. For certain cases there could be `targets` without the `source`. `Map` is getting constructed properly with `null` as a key, I have taken care of `equals and hashcode` in both `Source and Target` classes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 sort on Class member's property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095224/java-8-sort-on-class-members-property)

Comment: @tgdavies as I have posted, I have tried similar approach but it is not working for `null` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Comparator.nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) or [`Comparator.nullsFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) should be applied to handle possible `null` values in the compared items:

```java
finalResponses.sort(Comparator.nullsLast(
    Comparator.comparing(fr -> fr.getSource().getSourceId())
));
```

or like this:

```java
finalResponses.sort(Comparator.comparing(
    fr -> fr.getSource().getSourceId(),
    Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())
));
```